# ValueError when asking if a list of length-2 arrays contains a given length-1 array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a list containing arrays of different lengths and want to check if certain arrays are inside the list. Such a check is for example

```
from numpy import array
array([0]) in [array([0]), array([1,2])]
>>> True
```

However, if the list contains only arrays of a length bigger than the element to check, I get this error

```
array([0]) in [array([1,2])]
>>> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Now, my questions are (a) can someone help me to understand this and (b) how should one realize such an element-check instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you swap your elements, you get an error even if your list contains the target array:

```
>>> array([0]) in [array([1,2]), array([0])]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any
() or a.all()
```

In your original example of `array([0]) in [array([0]), array([1,2])]`, the second element is never tested since the first element passed the equality test.

You could get around this by first restricting to elements of the right shape:

```
>>> arrs =  [array([0]), array([1,2])]
>>> array([0]) in [a for a in arrs if a.shape == (1,)]
True
>>> arrs =  [array([1,2]), array([0])]
>>> array([0]) in [a for a in arrs if a.shape == (1,)]
True
>>>
```

However if you can explain your set-up and examples of data a bit more, there is normally a better and faster NumPy way that we can show you. What's the reason you have a list of NumPy arrays?

Comment: The reason is, this list goes through some nontrivial algorithms, where arrays of various lengths are removed and appended dynamically. The elements are of different length and their number varies, so I thought it's best to use a list as the outer structure. I guess my misconception reduces to the fact, that I expect `a==b` to be `False` for arrays of different lengths, but instead it gives an error.